# Image Choose For Android using Java Extension in Game Maker Studio

Tags: java, android, game-maker

Im trying to make a Java extension for a Game Maker Studio Android App.

I have tried to use code from online tutorials but GMS uses a different approach and I cant get it to work.

I am using the code below:

```
package ${YYAndroidPackageName};

//Basic imports
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.String;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

//Import Game Maker classes
import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.R;
import com.yoyogames.runner.RunnerJNILib;
import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.RunnerActivity;

public class pickimage extends Activity {

    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL = 70;

    public void selectimage() 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
        int dsMapIndex = RunnerJNILib.jCreateDsMap(null, null, null);
        RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "type", "pickeropened" );
        RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddDouble( dsMapIndex, "argument0", 2);
        RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddDouble( dsMapIndex, "argument0", 3);
        RunnerJNILib.CreateAsynEventWithDSMap(dsMapIndex, EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        URI selectedImageUri = null;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                selectedImageUri = new URI(data.getData());
                //String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                //Log.i("yoyo", selectedImagePath);
                //return selectedImagePath;
    int dsMapIndex = RunnerJNILib.jCreateDsMap(null, null,null);
    RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "type", "imagepath" );
    RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "path", selectedImagePath);
    RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "path", "boo");
    RunnerJNILib.CreateAsynEventWithDSMap(dsMapIndex, EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * helper to retrieve the path of an image URI

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            // just some safety built in 
            if( uri == null ) {
                // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
                return null;
            }
            // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
            // this will only work for images selected from gallery
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if( cursor != null ){
                int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            // this is our fallback here
            return uri.getPath();
    }*/

}
```

I have followed the GMS extension tutorial and it doesnt work.  Here are some error notices from the console:

```
:com.companyname.Test_Image_Chooser:compileReleaseJavaWithJavacF:\GM\Cache\Test_Image_Chooser\Android\Default\com.companyname.Test_Image_Chooser\src\main\java\com\companyname\Test_Image_Chooser\pickimage.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                               ^
  symbol:   variable SELECT_PICTURE
  location: class pickimage
F:\GM\Cache\Test_Image_Chooser\Android\Default\com.companyname.Test_Image_Chooser\src\main\java\com\companyname\Test_Image_Chooser\pickimage.java:42: error: incompatible types: Uri cannot be converted to String
                selectedImageUri = new URI(data.getData());
                                                       ^
F:\GM\Cache\Test_Image_Chooser\Android\Default\com.companyname.Test_Image_Chooser\src\main\java\com\companyname\Test_Image_Chooser\pickimage.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
    RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "path", selectedImagePath);
                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable selectedImagePath
  location: class pickimage
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':com.companyname.Test_Image_Chooser:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
```

What I am looking to implement is user presses a button in app, it opens the Native Image Picker Dialog, user selects a file.  Then user presses another button and the app gets the full path of the selected image and then I upload it to my server.

Im new to Java :)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues in your java file, when using intents you must notify the jnirunner that you are activating the intent, and also you have an extra unneeded argument in there and other extra stuff, so this part of your code

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
int dsMapIndex = RunnerJNILib.jCreateDsMap(null, null, null);
    RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "type", "pickeropened" );
    RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddDouble( dsMapIndex, "argument0", 2);
    RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddDouble( dsMapIndex, "argument0", 3);
    RunnerJNILib.CreateAsynEventWithDSMap(dsMapIndex, EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL);
```

should simply look more like this and have a connector statement before it to notify the runner, and don't call the async event at this time:

```
RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

And so in your onActivityResult code you have commented out the important part of the code, so the async event is not getting the info it needs, and there's some extra stuff in there and the "path" code line you have stated twice with different output variables, so this

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    URI selectedImageUri = null;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            selectedImageUri = new URI(data.getData());
            //String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            //Log.i("yoyo", selectedImagePath);
            //return selectedImagePath;
            int dsMapIndex = RunnerJNILib.jCreateDsMap(null, null,null);
            RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "type", "imagepath" );
            RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "path", selectedImagePath);
            RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "path", "boo");
            RunnerJNILib.CreateAsynEventWithDSMap(dsMapIndex, EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL);
        }
    }
}
```

should become this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            String path = data.getData().toString());
            Log.i("yoyo", path);
            int dsMapIndex = RunnerJNILib.jCreateDsMap(null, null,null);
            RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "type", "imagepath" );
            RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString(result, "selectedImageUri", path);
            RunnerJNILib.CreateAsynEventWithDSMap(dsMapIndex, EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL);
        }
    }
}
```